# Add custom field in email Opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, opencart2.x

I am using Opencart 2.1.0.1.  I have added some custom fields on the registration page. How do I display these custom fields in the email that gets send out to the store admin?

Below is the code for the standard fields:

```
// Send to main admin email if new account email is enabled
    if ($this->config->get('config_account_mail')) {
        $message  = $this->language->get('text_signup') . "\n\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_website') . ' ' . html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_name'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_firstname') . ' ' . $data['firstname'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_lastname') . ' ' . $data['lastname'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_customer_group') . ' ' . $customer_group_info['name'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_email') . ' '  .  $data['email'] . "\n";
        $message .= $this->language->get('text_telephone') . ' ' . $data['telephone'] . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your custom field in email message along with existing field.

`$message .= $this->language->get('text_custom_field') . ' ' . $data['custom_field'] . "\n"`;

Now add custom field text in catalog/language/en-gb/mail/customer.php

```
$_['text_custom_field']          = 'Custom field:';
```

You will get $data['custom_field'] value if you are passing it from frontend form.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use your advice, but in email it says Array instead some information  http://imgur.com/kxBoEq9

Comment: check value of $data['custom_field'] before passing to email function